# Inside cache, offline.html is always React's index.html

Tags: reactjs, caching, service-worker, workbox, serve

I am caching an `offline.html` page. The cache is created properly and even an `offline.html` page is present inside the cache. Additionally, the build folder also has the right HTML file. However, the content of the `offline.html` is always React's `index.html` in both cache and source tab of the Chrome dev tools. Where is my mistake? Could this be an issue with serve?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `serve -s build` uses index.html for all not found requests because of the -s flag.

Comment: Can you share your code? Since I am also having the same issue.